# Can't Connect Google Tag Manager to Meta. Getting "Publishing failed."

Tags: facebook, tagging, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side, facebook-conversions-api

I am in need of assistance with my Meta's Conversion API and Google Tag Manager setup. I have successfully set up a web and server container, with the server container being manually configured and running on AWS.

I am currently working on the "Publish resources" section, but am encountering an error that says "Publishing failed. We were unable to publish the resources to your Google Tag Manager account. Please try again." I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide some guidance in resolving this issue.

For reference, my web container is running on web.example.com, the tagging server is running on tagging.example.com, and the preview server is running on debug.tagging.example.com. I have followed this guide to set up my server-side tag manager on AWS: [deploy-server-side-google-tag-manager-aws/](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/deploy-server-side-google-tag-manager-aws/).

Here are some screenshots:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2zo8.png)

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc8KW.png)

[Console error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9WDQ.png)

I google-searched for this error and all I can find is other people with the same error but no solution was provided. I have also emailed Google and Meta support but I haven't gotten a response yet.

Comment: can you publish an empty container, with no meta tag in it?

Comment: could you please clarify the question for me? This is my first time working with these tools. I'm a junior developer.

Comment: In GTM, you have to publish a container in order for any work in it to get to production. If you try loading a never-published GTM container on a site, it will give a 404 like on one of your screenshots. Where do you get the first screenshot from though? Is that GTM?

Comment: The error is from Facebook. My server container on GTM is published. I suspect that it may be because my tagging server is not a subdomain of the main website. When I use example.com (instead of web.example.com) as my web server I don't get this error. Could this be the problem and if so is there a workaround?